# Can I get a list of all Shared Mailboxes using Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I would like to get a list of all the Shared mail boxes on my exchange server. An then I require to get details of each member of the shared mail boxes. How to achieve this via the graph api

I know we can do this via powershell but I would like to use the rest APIs in my javascript application.

I've come across multiple threads/forums claiming that microsoft had this in roadmap so have they implemented it?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a supported scenario with Microsoft Graph. For administrative managing and reporting of Exchange, you'll need to use PowerShell.