# How can filter groups in microsoft graph endpoint?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'd like to get only `Microsoft 365 groups`, `Distribution groups`, `Shared mailboxes` using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` endpoint.

But really cannot figure out what query I should use.

In the documentation, it has only example for `Microsoft 365 groups`. But can't understand how I have to make query to only get those 3 types of groups...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, listing `Shared mailboxes` is not supported by Microsoft Graph.

We can only get the particular shared mailbox like this (treat it as a user):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{shared mailbox email address}
```

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525437/can-i-get-a-list-of-all-shared-mailboxes-using-microsoft-graph-api) and User Voice [request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/15438267-support-the-discoverability-of-shared-mailboxes).

Secondly, for getting only `Microsoft 365 groups` and `Distribution groups`, please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[image]

We can filter the groups based on the `groupType`, `mailEnabled` and `securityEnabled` property. Here are the sample requests.

**List Microsoft 365 groups:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'Unified')
```

**List Distribution groups:** If we filter with `/groups?$filter=mailEnabled eq true and securityEnabled eq false`, the result will contain Microsoft 365 Groups. But we cannot easily filter for non-O365 group with **groupTypes** property. So listing Distribution groups directly with Microsoft Graph is not supported. We need to get the group list first and then do in-memory filter in our code.

**List Microsoft 365 groups and Distribution groups:** The same as **List Distribution groups**.

Comment: Great answer btw. I will try.